# How to parse XML which is stored in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing

I want to parse XML which is stored in a column in SQL Server:

[Table column with XML in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79sCJ.png)

and the XML is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <propertylist id="root">
       <property expanded="Y" id="createsdi" selectedindex="0" type="collection">
          <collection>
             <propertylist id="1305619640064">
                <property expanded="Y" id="columnvalues" selectedindex="0" type="collection">
                   <collection>
                      <propertylist id="1396440519721" />
                   </collection>
                </property>
                <property expanded="Y" id="tests" selectedindex="0" type="collection">
                   <collection>
                      <propertylist id="p1602059752707" sequence="1000000">
                         <property id="id" type="simple"><![CDATA[item1]]></property>
                         <property id="workitemid" type="simple"><![CDATA[SOURAVTESTER|1]]></property>
                      </propertylist>
                   </collection>
                </property>
                <property expanded="Y" id="specs" selectedindex="0" type="collection">
                   <collection>
                      <propertylist id="p1602059825237" sequence="1000000">
   

                  <property id="id" type="simple"><![CDATA[item1]]></property>
                     <property id="specid" type="simple"><![CDATA[EMSpec|1]]></property>
                  </propertylist>
               </collection>
            </property>
         </propertylist>
      </collection>
   </property>
   <property expanded="Y" id="workorder" type="propertylist">
      <propertylist id="root_0">
         <property expanded="Y" id="graceperiod" type="propertylist">
            <propertylist id="root_0_workorder_0">
               <property expanded="Y" id="graceperiod" type="propertylist">
                  <propertylist id="root_0_workorder_0_graceperiod_0" />
               </property>
               <property expanded="Y" id="deviation" type="propertylist">
                  <propertylist id="root_0_workorder_0_graceperiod_0" />
               </property>
            </propertylist>
         </property>
      </propertylist>
   </property>
</propertylist>
```

How can I parse the values of workitemid, specid?

I have written the following code

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ParentPropertyId = xc.value('(../@id)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    WorkItemId = xc.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    scheduleplanitem
CROSS APPLY
    valuetree.nodes('//propertylist/property[@id="workitemid"]') xt(xc)
```

but I get an error

> The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml

The result should be:

```
workitemid  SOURAVTESTER
specid      EMSpec
```

Comment: Please edit your post and specify desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It does the following:

- Removes XML prolog with the UTF-8 encoding. SQL Server implicitly converts any XML internally to UTF-16.
- Converts NVARCHAR() data type to XML data    type. After that XQuery
  methods to handle XML become available.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (col) VALUES
(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<propertylist id="root">
    <property expanded="Y" id="createsdi" selectedindex="0" type="collection">
        <collection>
            <propertylist id="1305619640064">
                <property expanded="Y" id="columnvalues" selectedindex="0"
                          type="collection">
                    <collection>
                        <propertylist id="1396440519721"/>
                    </collection>
                </property>
                <property expanded="Y" id="tests" selectedindex="0"
                          type="collection">
                    <collection>
                        <propertylist id="p1602059752707" sequence="1000000">
                            <property id="id" type="simple"><![CDATA[item1]]></property>
                            <property id="workitemid" type="simple"><![CDATA[SOURAVTESTER|1]]></property>
                        </propertylist>
                    </collection>
                </property>
                <property expanded="Y" id="specs" selectedindex="0"
                          type="collection">
                    <collection>
                        <propertylist id="p1602059825237" sequence="1000000">


                            <property id="id" type="simple"><![CDATA[item1]]></property>
                            <property id="specid" type="simple"><![CDATA[EMSpec|1]]></property>
                        </propertylist>
                    </collection>
                </property>
            </propertylist>
        </collection>
    </property>
    <property expanded="Y" id="workorder" type="propertylist">
        <propertylist id="root_0">
            <property expanded="Y" id="graceperiod" type="propertylist">
                <propertylist id="root_0_workorder_0">
                    <property expanded="Y" id="graceperiod" type="propertylist">
                        <propertylist id="root_0_workorder_0_graceperiod_0"/>
                    </property>
                    <property expanded="Y" id="deviation" type="propertylist">
                        <propertylist id="root_0_workorder_0_graceperiod_0"/>
                    </property>
                </propertylist>
            </property>
        </propertylist>
    </property>
</propertylist>')
, (NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

--DECLARE @startPos INT = LEN('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>') + 1;
DECLARE @prolog NVARCHAR(100) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID
        --, TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(col
        --  , @startPos
        --  , LEN(col)) AS XML) AS xmldata
        , TRY_CAST('<root>' + REPLACE(col, @prolog, '') + '</root>' AS XML) AS xmldata  FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Item
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('//property[@id=("specid","workitemid")]') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------+
| ID |      Item      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | SOURAVTESTER|1 |
|  1 | EMSpec|1       |
+----+----------------+
```

Comment: There is a column with all the XML. I have to check all the XML and find the values. Please check the image attached the description.

Comment: @sourav, it is your responsibly to provide a DDL and sample data population. Not pictures  of i t.

Comment: @sourav, I adjusted the answer.

Comment: 'Table column with XML in this picture' - please check the link above sir.

Comment: @sourav, I adjusted the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks sir, I got the result. but can it be dynamic? I mean if we take the XML from the coumn itself.

Comment: @sourav, it is not clear what it means "dynamic". Please clarify. The solution I provided is taking XML directly from the DB table column.

Comment: I can not declare the XML in the query. I have to take the XML from the column of that table.

Comment: @sourav, There is no need to declare anything. In your real environment, you need to ignore my DDL and sample data population section, and concentrate just on the CTE and `SELECT` part. There you need to substitute (1) **@tbl** with your real table name, (2) **col** with your real column name.

Comment: I can not understand, for table name scheduleplanitem and column name valuetree what would be the query.

Comment: @sourav, it is the same query. Just replace **@tbl** with the **scheduleplanitem**, and **col** with the **valuetree**.